# How to prove that a function defined by an inf is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have been stuck on this problem for 2 days.

We have a function $f_A$ defined by :
$f_A(x)= \text{inf}(|x−a|,a\in A)$
with $A\subset \mathbb{R}$

We fix $x$ consider the special case where there is $\epsilon$ $>0$ such as $]x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon[ \subset A$

We want to show that $f_A$ is differentiable at $x$ and we want the value of $f_A'(x)$

I tried calculating the limit as $h$ approaching $0$ of $(f_A(x-h)-f_A(x)) / h$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the statement of your problem, we have that a open interval containing $x$ is contained in $A$. Doesn't that mean there is a neighborhood of $x$ such that $f_A$ is constant with value $0$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried thinking this way but I am having a hard time seeing why $f_A$ shall be constant on a neighborhood of x...

Comment: If we know that $a \in A$, then of course be the element of $A$ closest to $a$ would be $a$ itself.

Comment: I believe the notation was to indicate an *open* interval around $x$ is contained in $A$.  But the implication still follows: $f_A(x) = 0$ and is identically zero on an open interval surrounding $x$.

Comment: Edited, thanks for the observation.

Comment: If this is not an answer but an inquisition, consider writing a comment rather than an answer.